# Converting a fraction into a decimal with integers in C++

Tags: c++, integer, division, greatest-common-divisor

Yes. It's an assignment, that is quite a brain teaser for me to be honest.. The goal of the program, or "problem" (if you want to look at it in math terms) is dividing two numbers against each other. You are able to divide whole numbers, and fractions against each other. The function definition looks like this:

```
bool divide(int c1, int n1, int d1, int c2, int n2, int d2, char result[], int len)
```

**c1, c2** - Whole numbers

**n1, n2** - Numerator 1, Numerator 2

**d1, d2** - Denominator 1, Denominator 2

**result[ ]** - The character array that is to display the answer

**len** - The number of characters allowed in result []

---

I would simply use long division and find my answer this way but since there is a restriction to not use **double**, **float**, or **string** I am more limited in my options towards my approach.

The good news is I've gotten a far ways towards the end solution and would like to ask for **advice** as what my next move might be. This is my process thus far:

1) Convert each number to an improper fraction

2) Take result 1 * (1 / result 2 )

3) Find the whole number part of the solution (if there is one)

4) (From the improper fraction) Take the numerator % denominator to find my new numerator for the mixed fraction I have

5) I am now here, trying to find a base 10 multiple for the denominator so I can represent the mixed fraction in decimal format.. Any pointers would be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

(A/B) / (C/D) = (A/B) x (D/C) = (AD) / (BC)

So just compute AD and BC, then reduce to lowest terms.

If you want to actually do the division, do it the same way you do it on paper.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I've got the algorithm working up to that point. Might there another way of representing this fraction as a decimal other than finding a base-10 equivalent denominator of the fraction?

Comment: @Zac Actually perform the long division, just as you would on paper.